# peewee + mysql, how to make sure emoji are properly stored and retrieved (getting ?'s)

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have emoji stored in varchar column in MYSQL8, with charset utf8mb4 encoding utf8mb4_unicode_ci
I am getting the value with peewee and I'm getting ?'s instead.

What may I be doing wrong? What else do I have to do to make sure emojis come through intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try setting `charset='utf8mb4` in your db constructor:

```
MySQLDatabase(..., charset='utf8mb4')
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought use_unicode was enough...